# How to make process stop running with keystroke

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, user-interface, frameworks

When I run my selenium framework it runs as a process. There is no user interface. It runs until it completes or until it encounters an exception that stops the test. Currently, the only way to manually stop the test is to kill the process in Task Manager.

I would like the user to be able to press a key, like escape, to stop the process.

I've only so far been able to find such functions related to a project running in a console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a batchfile with the following contents:

```
taskkill /F /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe"
```

(replace 'notepad.exe' with the correct program name)

When you create a link to that batch-file, you can also specify a 'Shortcut key' to start this batchfile.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Luuk. To work around I created a batch file that is now included in the build.